# Rendering Area does not change when GLFW window is re-sized

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm switching from GLUT to GLFW to find that when I re-size my GLFW window, the rendering region does not change. (IE, the content being rendered stays in the same place as it was in the old window size, and the new window area is filled with the clear color.) Do I need to take more steps to re-size the context or something such as that?

Comment: What are you doing when the window is resized? Are you using the function `glViewport()`? http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml

Comment: Post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: No. I was used to GLUT doing that for me. Beginner's Error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to re-size the viewport to match the size of your window.

Use `glViewport();`